# Issue retrieving WSDL Definition from Publisher Portal after migration using WSO2 APICTL 4.1.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Issue retrieving WSDL Definition from Publisher Portal after migration the API from Dev Env to Prod Env using WSO2 APICTL 4.1.0
we have executed those command and we didn't get any error :

apictl login dev --username xxxxx  --password xxxxxx -k

apictl login prod --username xxxxx --password xxxxxx -k

apictl export api -n phoneverify -v v1 -e dev --preserve-status=true --format JSON -k

apictl import api -f dev/phoneverify_v1.zip -e prod -k

we got response :

Successfully imported API.

you can reproduce this issue even with this API :
http://ws.cdyne.com/phoneverify/phoneverify.asmx

Find attached screenshot :
Dev Env
[image]

Prod env

[image]

The carbon logs showing this error :

```
[2023-09-13 10:12:05,920] ERROR - GlobalThrowableMapper 900684:WSDL Not Found::No WSDL Available for the API phoneverify:v1
```

Comment: This worked fine for me. What is the APIM distribution you used to test this? was it the one from github or the one from the website? What is the APICTL version you used, can you test with the latest APICTL release as well?
Check whether there is the WSDL definition is available in the exported zip file in WSDL directory.

Comment: This issue is related to the operating system i think ,you can reproduce this issue on windows .(APIM V 4.1.0 and apictl 4.1.0 ) https://github.com/wso2/api-manager/issues/2174

Comment: https://github.com/wso2/api-manager/issues/2181

Comment: As you mentioned the issue is there it seems for the published APIs, this will be fixed as an update and in the public branch soon.